# Passing custom parameters to an animation when using a @HostBinding?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-animations

[In this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pf4wte?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslide-in-animation.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fanimation.ts) the animation state is being passed to the animation via a `@HostBinding` like this:

```
 @HostBinding('@slide')
  get currentAnimationState() {
    return this.animationState;
}
```

This is so that the component host element can be animated.

If we want to pass custom parameters to the animation, which is typically done by binding the animation to the element like this:

```
<div class="header" [@slide]="{value:animationState,params:{width:width}}" >
```

How would we go about that?